# Create file dynamically as File object and then publish

Tags: silverstripe-4

It's evidently a little more complicated to create a file dynamically in SS4

```
$folder = Folder::find_or_make('Cards');
$filename = 'myimage.jpg';
$contents = file_get_contents('http://example.com/image.jpg');
$pathToFile = Controller::join_links(Director::baseFolder(), ASSETS_DIR, $folder->Title, $filename);
file_put_contents($pathToFile, $contents);

$image = Image::create();

$image->ParentID = $folder->ID;
$image->Title = "My title";
$image->Name = $filename;
$image->FileFilename = 'Cards/' . $filename;
$image->write();

Member::actAs(Member::get()->first(), function() use ($image, $folder) {
    if (!$image->isPublished()) {
        $image->publishFile();
        $image->publishSingle();
    }
    if (!$folder->isPublished()) {
        $folder->publishSingle();
    }
});
```

The above, creates the file as expected in `/assets/Cards/myimage.jpg` and publishes it fine

However all previews are blank, so it's obviously not finding the file:

[image: All previews are blank]

Any idea what I missed in creating the `Image` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$folder = Folder::find_or_make('Cards');
$contents = file_get_contents('http://example.com/image.jpg');

$img = Image::create();
$img->setFromString($contents, 'image.jpg');
$img->ParentID = $parent->ID;
$img->write();

// This is needed to build the thumbnails
\SilverStripe\AssetAdmin\Controller\AssetAdmin::create()->generateThumbnails($img);
$img->publishSingle();
```

FYI: `$img->Filename` no longer exists. An `Image` or `File` object have a `File` property, which is a composite field of type `DBFile`. This composite fields contains the filename, hash and a variant…
So you should use the composite field to address these fields.

Comment: Note that if you have S3 you will need to call `$img->publishFile()`